# How does Windows process scheduler dispatch threads to CPU?

Tags: windows, cpu

I have a web application running on Tomcat hosted on a VM running Windows 2016 with 8 vCPU cores over 4 vSockets (so, 4x 2cores). Windows doesn't see any NUMA nodes or hyperthreading cores.

We noticed a strange CPU usage pattern: vCPUs 0, 2, and 4 usage is higher then the others. These happen to be the first core of sockets 0, 1, and 2.

How does Windows process scheduler dispatch threads? does it balance the load across sockets before using the additional cores per socket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my pc prefer even numbered cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014168/why-does-my-pc-prefer-even-numbered-cores)

Comment: Thank you @RaymondChen, but that question clearly refer to hyperthreading, which is not the case with my VM: Windows don't see any logical core due to hyperthreading.